# WMDC not starting?

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-7, wmdc

I am trying to start windows mobile device center on windows 7 machine. But it only shows me the small green window that is shown at loading time[image]
 and then it is closed automatically. I am not getting what the problem is.

I tried to uninstall the previous update then re-installed again but the problem is not gone.

Guys please help me out. I need to debug my app and submit its build today.

Thanks,

Madhup

Comment: This suits better on SuperUser.com in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried soft resetting the device you're trying to connect? Have you rebooted the Windows 7 machine you're trying to connect to?

Can you see the WMDC icon in the sys tray? If so, click on it to open WMDC and see what it says.

Go to Control Panel -> Sync Center and delete the existing partnership of the device you're trying to connect.

Answer (score -1):

Trie to change Windows mobile services right from Local service to Local system
Clvac